# MySQL UPDATE SUBQUERY CASE WHERE (all at once)

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction when query the statement below.

The idea on this query is to update a value column on the 'Realm' table... but the information that I need is in another table (enterprise_feature link to enterprise). Also, I have a condition (where clause) that only can be found in the 'user' table.

Can someone help me figure it out what am I missing here? I really appreciate.

```
UPDATE realm r
      LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = r.owner_id
      LEFT JOIN enterprise e ON e.id = r.pricing_plan_id
      LEFT JOIN enterprise_feature ef ON ef.enterprise_id = e.id
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT enterprise_id, SUM(feature_flag_id) "A" 
                 FROM enterprise_feature ef) x ON e.id = x.enterprise_id
SET r.feature_flags =  
CASE
  WHEN r.feature_flags <> -1 THEN r.feature_flags+67108864
  WHEN r.feature_flags = -1 THEN x.A+67108864  
END
, r.updated_at = SYSDATE()
WHERE r.pricing_plan_id = '161' AND u.premium_support = '1' AND r.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Without a 'WHERE something IS NULL' clause, an OUTER JOIN in an UPDATE statement is a rare thing. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The WHERE... IS NULL is actually irrelevant on this query. I just edited my question.
Goal here is to update a value in one table based on another but considering that condition in WHERE clause is accepted.

Comment: It's just not clear. Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.